# How to see resampled data after BOOTSTRAP

Tags: matlab, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I was trying to resample (with replacement) my database using 'bootstrap' in Matlab as follows:

```
D = load('Data.txt');
lead = D(:,1);
depth = D(:,2);
X = D(:,3);
Y = D(:,4);

%Bootstraping to resample 100 times
[resampling100,bootsam] = bootstrp(100,'corr',lead,depth);

%plottig the bootstraping result as histogram
hist(resampling100,10);
... ... ...
... ... ...
```

Though the script written above is correct, I wonder how I would be able to see/load the resampled 100 datasets created through bootstrap? 'bootsam(:)' display the indices of the data/values selected for the bootstrap samples, but not the new sample values!! Isn't it funny that I'm creating fake data from my original data and I can't even see what is created behind the scene?!?

My second question: is it possible to resample the whole matrix (in this case, D) altogether without using any function? However, I know how to create random values from a vector data using 'unidrnd'.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The indices in `bootsam` allow you to recover the resampled data, eg `lead(bootsam(:, n))` will give you the `nth` resampled dataset from `lead`. To resample the whole matrix `D` you would use a function like `unidrnd` - although personally I'd use `randi`. Not sure what you mean by "without using any function". Everything in Matlab uses functions :-)  Let me know if I've misunderstood. If not, I'll convert this to an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved the first part. I meant 'no function' as @fun; e.g. @mean. By the way, I didn't get how you would create the whole database using randi. r = randi(imax,size(D)) don't seem to work!

Comment: I've provided some more information in an answer to this question. If you think I've solved the problem, then feel free to click the tick mark next to my response. If not, then let me know, and I'll see if I can improve the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is that `bootsam` provides the indices of the resampled data. Specifically, the `nth` column of `bootsam` provides the indices of the `nth` resampled dataset. In your case, to obtain the `nth` resampled dataset you would use:

```
lead_resample_n = lead(bootsam(:, n));
depth_resample_n = depth(bootsam(:, n));
```

Regarding the second question, I'm guessing what you mean is, how would you just get a re-sampled dataset without worrying about applying a function to the resampled data. Personally, I would use `randi`, but in this situation, it is irrelevant whether you use `randi` or `unidrnd`. An example follows that assumes 4 columns of some data matrix `D` (as in your question):

```
%# Build an example dataset
T = 10;
D = randn(T, 4);

%# Obtain a set of random indices, ie indices of draws with replacement
Ind = randi(T, T, 1);

%# Obtain the resampled data
DResampled = D(Ind, :);
```

To create multiple re-sampled data, you can simply loop over the creation of random indices. Or you could do it in one step by creating a matrix of random indices and using that to index `D`. With careful use of `reshape` and `permute` you can turn this into a `T*4*M` array, where indexing `m = 1, ..., M` along the third dimension yields the `mth` resampled dataset. Example code follows:

```
%# Build an example dataset
T = 10;
M = 3;
D = randn(T, 4);

%# Obtain a set of random indices, ie indices of draws with replacement
Ind = randi(T, T, M);

%# Obtain the resampled data
DResampled = permute(reshape(D(Ind, :)', 4, T, []), [2 1 3]);
```

Comment: I should definitely give the answer a check though you are still confused with the second part. Here, D = [[lead]',[depth]',[X]',[Y]'], I want to create a matrix, D1 = [[resampled lead]',[resampled depth]',[resampled X]',[resampled Y]'] in one ago. However, what you did can also be done as:
N= 1000;
rowindex = unidrnd(N,N,1);
depth_new = depth(rowindex);
lead_new = lead(rowindex);
R = unidrnd(100,[As,depth]);
OR,
n = 25;        %size of each data set
nReps = 2000;  %number of data sets or 'experiments'
id = ceil(rand(n,nReps)*n);
bootstrapData = depth(id);

Comment: @user1797104 I've updated the answer with a little more detail. Admittedly I'm still not sure what you're really after with that second question :-)  Hope this helps though!